# SSRS2008 is not deploying

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am Using SSRS2008 and want to deploy it on Report Server, all the configure data on my Local system.
when I am  trying to deploy Reports it is asking for "Service Report Login" and could not pass any credentials.
side wise I am accessing Report server by URL in browser(localhost/Reports) then it is showing Blank Page .

Any Idea.
Thanks in Advance.

Manjeet Singh

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is that you can access reporting services URL from the machine it is installed on. You will need to log into the machine SSRS is running on, either physically or by RDP.  When you install SSRS on a machine, the only account which is configured by default to access SSRS is the account which was used to install SSRS.

Go to the reporting services URL that was set up ([see this article](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/12/tutorials/26/tutorials/4600/getting-started-with-ssrs-part-4-configuring-sql-server-reporting-services-in-windows-server-2008.aspx))  Once you have access SSRS via the url, this will then allow you to set up an account with suitable permissions to access the SSRS URL.

Comment: Reporting Server configuration is done already , even when I deploy the report as an Administrator it is deploying properly , but when I am accessing the ReportSever by URL is not accessible, and showing an error, and when I am accessing Reports it is showing blank Page.

Answer (score 0):

Three things when running SSRS and deploying:

1. Ensure you can get to http:// (servername)/Reports.  You should have a tool set up called 'Reporting Services Configuration Manager'.  It is under All Programs>Microsoft SQL  Server 2008>Configuration Tools.  It will have paths set up 'Web Service URL' and 'Report Manager URL' on it's left pane.  Usually I log in as the default admin of the (Servername) machine remotely and ensure it is set up.
2. You need to ensure that your USER (or domain group) of the machine you are deploying from can access these locations.  If they are not coming up at all you have issues at a lower level than just deployment.  Generally the default admin can add new users as a first setup routine.  Go in to the webpage, /Reports, hit 'Folder Settings' at the main and ad your user or group under 'Security' as 'Content Manager' which is the highest level.
3. You deploy to the Web Service NOT the web page.  http:// (servername)/ReportServer NOT /Reports.  One is the actual service that does the requests, the other is just shell for viewers to see content and maintain security.  Set this under your projects properties with the url.

Other thoughts:

If you set up special firewalls you need to ensure you can access the location of your SSRS server on remote machine, not just locally.  You should be able to deploy to a server from a client machine, not just locally.   Ensure your version of SQL Server is not prior to the version you are trying to deploy to.  SQL 2005 does not work with 2008 server direclty, you need to update the RDL first to my knowledge.

Comment: SSRS configured properly in Configuration Manager, but When I accessing using URL it is not showing on Browser, And showing blank page , and also when I am accessing using ReportServer It is showing an error." Reporting Services Error"

    The permissions granted to user 'manjeet-PC\manjeet' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) Get Online Help.

Comment: It is not running correctly for your user then.  Can you ensure you can do step 2 as the local admin of (servername) machine?  If you can get in there you should be able to add your user.

Comment: when I am accessing reports folder using URL it is asking for User id password and after that is shows the blank page of reports.

Comment: That is common with first time access,  you need to use the local administrator of the server of the machine hosting the SSRS site.  By default on local admins have access.  Generally this is the user that set up SQL Server (version) on the machine.  Once in you can add other users.